# Python - Beautifulsoup - If elements not found on page skip these elements and find remaining

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently running the code below on the site below to **scrape** match date and channels showing each match

https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts

I have tags named hometeam and awayteam which find tags containing the hometeam and awayteam of matches where two competitors are named. When I run the code I currently have all the data is returned correctly (see screenshot below):

[image: correctoutput]

Example URL received the scrapes fine: https://sport-tv-guide.live/event/live-darts-world-matchplay-aspinall-nathan-van-den-bergh-dimitri/525424?id=9307211800

The issue I am having is if there is a page url that is loaded that doesn't contain these two elements, none of the remaining elements that should be scraped are returned either and no content is returned at all, even though all elements except for hometeam and awayteam are present on these pages (see screenshot below).

[image: missingotherelements]

Example URL received that doesn't scrape correctly - https://sport-tv-guide.live/event/live-darts-2020-world-match-play-darts-dag-4?uid=721120925

I am unsure as to how I would prevent the script from stopping after hometeam and awayteam elements are not found and continue to find the other elements. I have tried switching the order of the elements that are scraped first, so that hometeam and awayteam would be the last elements to be scraped, but the same issue occurs.

My code is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2,22'}
    r = requests.post(url,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
   
def linkscrape(links):
    baseurl = "https://sport-tv-guide.live"
    urllist = []
    
    for link in links:
        finalurl = (baseurl+ link['href'])
        urllist.append(finalurl)
        # print(finalurl)
        
    for singleurl in urllist:
        soup2=makesoup(url=singleurl)
        print(singleurl)
        g_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'id': 'channelInfo'})
        c_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'liveOtherStations clearfix'})
        for match in g_data:
            try:
                hometeam =  match.find_previous('div', class_='cell40 text-center teamName1').text.strip()
                print(hometeam)
                awayteam =  match.find_previous('div', class_='cell40 text-center teamName2').text.strip()
                print(awayteam)
            except:
                pass
                print("Missing hometeam + awayteam elemets")
            startime =  match.find('div', class_='time full').text.strip()
            event=  match.find('div', class_='title full').text.strip()
            dateandtime = match.find('div', class_='date full').text.strip()
            sport = match.find('div', class_='text full').text.strip()
            for channel in c_data:
                channels = match.find('div', class_='stationLive active col-wrap')


                try:
                    print("Competitors; ", hometeam + "vs" + awayteam)
                except:
                    pass

                print("Time; ", startime) 
                print("Date:",  dateandtime)
                print("Event:",  event)
                print("Sport:",  sport)
                print("Channels:",  channel.text)
     
def matches():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts")
    linkscrape(links= soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'article flag',  'href' : True}))
```

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is that each URL that is scraped to be checked for hometeam and awayteam tags. If the particular URL contains these elements then all other elements such as event/dateandtime should also be scraped. If the particular URL doesn't contain hometeam and awayteam elements, these should be skipped and then the remaining tags such as event/dateandtime should still be scraped, instead of no information being outputted once hometeam and awayteam tags aren't found.

Thanks to anyone who can advise or provide a solution to this issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by placing each element in a try block. The elements now print correctly when available and are not shown if not available, as I had set the variable to "Element not found" but didn't print to console if not found. I will wait for a day or so, to see if anyone can provide a more elegant solution than using try blocks. If not, I will then post my answer to possibly help other people who may have a similar issue.